# Sympy : issue in Differentiation of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, derivative

the aim of this script is to obtain the standard deviation of the wind direction using U, V wind speed components and their respective standard wind speed deviation (std_u, std_v).

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

# wind direction calculation function
def f(u,v):
    return (270-180*sym.atan2(v,u)/sym.pi)%360 

u,v= sym.symbols('u v')

dfdu1 = diff(f(u,v),u).doit()
dfdv2 = diff(f(u,v),v).doit()

# example of value for the test
dfdu=dfdu1.evalf(subs={u: 2,v: 6}).doit()
dfdv=dfdv1.evalf(subs={u: 2,v: 6}).doit()
std_u=0.5
std_v=0.3

np.sqrt(float(dfdu**2*st_u**2+dfdv**2*std_v**2))
```

One of the result:

```
dfdu1=180*v*Subs(Derivative(Mod(_xi_1, 4), _xi_1), _xi_1, -2*atan2(v, u)/pi + 3)/(pi*(u**2 + v**2))

dfdv1=-180*u*Subs(Derivative(Mod(_xi_1, 4), _xi_1), _xi_1, -2*atan2(v, u)/pi + 3)/(pi*(u**2 + v**2))
```

I saw on github that this means that sympy is not yet able to determine the derivative of my function.

I have tried to break down the calculation but did not know what should be _xi_1 (I am not familiar with sympy)

Is there another way to do this calculation?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure the `%360` is necessary for computing the derivative. (And that is what is causing the trouble with the derivative being unevaluated.)

Comment: Ah It is indeed this term that blocks, I think I will do without for the derivation thank you!